# Compiling directive from its own linker function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive setup as follows:

```
angular.module('RecursiveDirective', []).
directive('item', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div><input type="text" ng-model="itemvalue"/></div>',
    link: ItemLinker,
    controller: 'ItemController',
    scope: {}
  }
  
  function ItemLinker(scope, element, attribute) {
    element.on('keyup', function(event) {
      var code = event.keyCode || event.which;
      if(code==13) {
        element.append('<item></item>');
        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
      }
    })
  }
}).
controller('ItemController', function($scope) {
  $scope.itemvalue = "Some Value";
})
```

Now i am trying to clone the element when a enter key is pressed on this directive element.

I am able to clone the directive but its not setting the scope correctly. Second clone onwards, the directive is resetting the previous value set on the directive involved in its cloning.

*How do i clone the directive, so that it gets its own fresh scope, like a newly initialized directive.*

[Plunker Here - http://plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/edit/BtEC5OmzajAQ9zFgZJzv)

### Edit

I have to create nesting structure using the directive i.e. directive item containing another directive item. The above problem is linear representation of the same.

So, i cannot use `ng-repeat` here. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
element.on('keyup', function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
```

If you don't stop propagation then the event bubbles up and you end up with every element being compiled again and every added item being added several times

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not create a recursive directive. You can just create an ng-repeat like this:

```
<item ng-repeat='item in vm.items'></item>
```

then check the on enter and add another items in `vm.items`

Answer (score 0):

Try this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xivDKNH0A2ZUG0Bdtj04).

```js
// Code goes here
angular.module('RecursiveDirective', []).
directive('item', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div  ng-repeat="itemvalue in inputs track by $index"><input ng-keyup="keyUp($event)" type="text" ng-model="itemvalue.value"/></div>',
    link: ItemLinker,
    controller:"ItemController",
    scope: {}
  }
  
  function ItemLinker(scope, element, attribute) {
    scope.keyUp = function(event){
      if(event.keyCode==13)
      {
          scope.inputs.push({value:""});
      }
    }
    scope.inputs =[{value:scope.itemvalue}];
  }
}).
controller('ItemController', function($scope) {
  $scope.itemvalue = "Some Value";
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="RecursiveDirective">
    <div></div>
    <item></item>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would like to compile the directive as ng-repeat is not suitable for me. As I have to nest directive within directive.

Comment: It is. It would help if you could suggest me a $compile based solution.

Comment: What exactly you try achieve?